# On inferring fmap for ADTs

Tags: haskell, functor, algebraic-data-types, bifunctor

Suppose that two new types are defined like this

```
type MyProductType a = (FType1 a, FType2 a)

type MyCoproductType a = Either (FType1 a) (FType2 a)
```

...and that `FType1` and `Ftype2` are both instances of `Functor`.

If one now were to declare `MyProductType` and `MyCoproductType` as instances of `Functor`, would the compiler *require* explicit definitions for their respective `fmap`'s, or can it infer these definitions from the previous ones?

Also, is the answer to this question implementation-dependent, or does it follow from the Haskell spec?

---

By way of background, this question was motivated by trying to make sense of a remark in [something I'm reading](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/02/03/functoriality/).  The author first defines

```
type Writer a = (a, String)
```

...and later writes (my emphasis)

> ...the `Writer` type constructor is functorial in `a`.  *We don't even have to implement `fmap` for it, because it's just a simple product type.*

The emphasized text is the remark I'm trying to make sense of.  I *thought* it meant that Haskell could infer `fmap`'s for *any* ADT based on functorial types, and, in particular, it could infer the `fmap` for a "simple product type" like `Writer`, but now I think this interpretation is not right (at least if I'm reading Ørjan Johansen's answer correctly).

As for what the author meant by that sentence, now I really have no clue.  Maybe all he meant is that it's not worth the trouble to re-define `Writer` in such a way that its functoriality can be made explicit, since it's such a "simple ... type".  (Grasping at straws here.)

Comment: You can't declare them `Functor`, because there are already instances for `(,)` and `Either`. If you instead use `newtype`, the instances are derivable using [`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/deriving.html#newtype-deriving).

Comment: You can use `fmap fmap fmap` to map a function over the inner Functor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you cannot generally define new instances for `type` synonyms, especially not partially applied ones as you would need in your case. I think you meant to define a `newtype` or `data` instead:

```
newtype MyProductType a = MP (FType1 a, FType2 a)
newtype MyCoproductType a = MC (Either (FType1 a) (FType2 a))
```

Standard Haskell says nothing about deriving `Functor` automatically at all, that is only possible with GHC's `DeriveFunctor` extension. (Or sometimes `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`, but that doesn't apply in your examples because you're not using `a` just as the last argument inside the constructor.)

So let's try that:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
data FType1 a = FType1 a deriving Functor
data FType2 a = FType2 a deriving Functor
newtype MyProductType a = MP (FType1 a, FType2 a) deriving Functor
newtype MyCoproductType a = MC (Either (FType1 a) (FType2 a)) deriving Functor
```

We get the error message:

```
Test.hs:6:76:
    Can't make a derived instance of ‘Functor MyCoproductType’:
      Constructor ‘MC’ must use the type variable only as the last argument of a data type
    In the newtype declaration for ‘MyCoproductType’
```

It turns out that GHC can derive the *first* three, but not the last one.  I believe the third one only works because tuples are special cased. `Either` doesn't work though, because GHC doesn't keep any special knowledge about how `Either` treats its *first* argument. It's nominally a *mathematical functor* in that argument, but not a *Haskell* `Functor`.

Note that GHC is smarter about using variables only as last argument of types known to be `Functor`s. The following works fine:

```
newtype MyWrappedType a = MW (Either (FType1 Int) (FType2 (Maybe a))) deriving Functor
```

So to sum up: It depends, GHC has an extension for this but it's not always smart enough to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks!  BTW, sorry for the invalid Haskell.  I took the code I posted from an exposition of category theory that uses Haskell for many examples, but the author does not always make clear when he's actually a Haskell-like-looking pseudo-code instead of bona fide Haskell.  I'll know better next time.

Comment: @kjo Your code with `type` was actually fine Haskell, it just doesn't work to add instances to those.

Comment: Ah!  I see.  Thanks for the clarification.